# A word for one who doesn't see his own flaws but always finds flaws in others?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

This person I know always mentions things as my flaws, mal-function, defect, etc. He has a lot of big flaws himself, but he never mention them, whereas he finds very small flaws in others.

I want a word for such a person. I know of captious, critic, sharp-tongued, fault-finder. Which one does best describe the person in question?

Comment: Please show us how to use this word in a sen­tence. Please show your prior re­search, in­clud­ing search­ing this site for in­nu­mer­able du­pli­cates. What reg­is­ter are you talk­ing here, a for­mal word or phrase one might use in a writ­ten con­text or in­stead one more suited to ca­sual con­ver­sa­tion? Are you look­ing for slang or id­ioms? What’s so wrong with *hyp­ocrite, hyp­o­crit­i­cal,* or *overly crit­i­cal* that we need a whole new ques­tion amidst a vast sea of nearly iden­ti­cal re­quests that have long ago yielded up an­swers like those three I’ve just now men­tioned?

Answer (score 2):

The phrase I think of is double standard.

> a rule or principle that is applied to some people but not others, in a way that is unfair

The person evaluates you with a set of standards that are not applied to himself. And that's unfair to you. He can be called a double standard person.

Answer (score 1):

I’ll offer you three words and each word has a context.

You could use the world hypocrite, but typically a hypocrite tells what is wrong and does the same wrong. Hypocrite is more action oriented versus a characterization.

You could use the word perfectionist, but this would assume that the perfectionist does not see his or her own flaws, much like hypocrite would justify their hypocrisy.

You could use the word narcissist, but this would assume that one understands the psychology that a narcissist often hides in the shadow of his or her own shortcomings by pointing out other’s mistakes and short comings.

Comment: +1 for "hypocrite"

Comment: "Hypocrite" is probably about as close as it gets. [Humbug](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Humbug) is another possibility if the OP doesn't mind somewhat dated language.